# How to change data on one spinner by onclick on another spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner

all i have two spinners spinner1 & spinner2. in one spinner i am showing names from database.(Ex. onkar) now if i select onkar name on spinner1 then all names must be occurred on spinner2 except name onkar.
i want to do like this.but i am not getting how to achieve it?
give me some sample or give idea for the same.

or can i change data of spinner dynamically????
Thanks in Advance--

Answer (score 2):

consider that u have used two adapters to set data to spinner when u select first spinner just remove that value from second adapter and then call method notifyDataSetChanged() it will change second spinner data.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
    // Step 1: Remove Data from ArrayList 1
    // Step 2: Adpater for first spinner .notifiyDataSetChanged()  

}
```

Comment: actually i want to remove selected element of first spinner from second spinner